# How to describe that function mutates an object by reference?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that modifies an object by reference:

```js
function addProp(object, value) {
  object.foo = value;
}
```

How to tell TypeScript that the `object` value changes its type after calling the `addProp` function? I expect a code like this:

```
interface WithProp<T> {
  foo: T;
}

function addProp<T1 extends object, T2>(object: T1 mutatesTo (T1 & WithProp<T2>), value: T2) {
  object.foo = value;
}

const obj = { bar: 'baz' };
obj.foo; // TS: error
addProp(obj, 123);
obj.foo; // TS: ok
```

Comment: Are we somewhat going around the reason for using typescript to begin with here? I think you need to add a return type to the function, which returns the mutated object, and I don't think it is possible to have the "TS-compilator" return error as you describe, because the "TS-compilator" have no way of knowing what will happen with your object at runtime. The best you can do is to let the compiler know that your object may change, and then you need to add multiple types to it.

Answer (score 2):

The type system isn't really geared toward mutating the types of variables.  It *does* use [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) to narrow the types of variables, at least in some code blocks, but until recently there was no way to write `addProp()` to trigger such control flow based narrowing.

TypeScript 3.7 introduced [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to represent functions which don't return a value but which guard against invalid states.  They are very new and have some [weird restrictions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33580), so be warned.

But what you can do now is to represent `addProp()` as an assertion function that says the input of type `T1` is now asserted to be the narrower type `T1 & WithProp<T2>`.  In this case, instead of throwing an error if the input isn't that type, the function implementation just *makes* it that type by adding the property.  But it's all the same to the type system.  Anyway, it looks like this:

```
function addProp<T1 extends object, T2>(
    o: T1,
    value: T2
): asserts o is T1 & WithProp<T2> {
    (o as T1 & WithProp<T2>).foo = value;
}
```

And then it behaves the way you want:

```
let obj = { bar: 'baz' };
obj.foo; // error! foo does not exist on {bar: string}
addProp(obj, 123);
obj.foo; // okay
```

Note that this narrowing is the result of control flow analysis, which gets reset on assignments, so you might be surprised that the following doesn't work (note I put `let` instead of `const` above):

```
// weirdness on reassignment
obj = { bar: "baz", foo: 1 }; // error! foo is extra
```

But this is the closest I can come to representing such mutations in the type system.  Okay, hope this helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwApQPYAOAPACoB8yA3gFDJ3Ix54BcyJA3NQL7XUwCuIBGGB4QyOABNJuQqQCMyCAA9IISQGdkeAEYArCMIA0bAExkAFLXos28o9boA3OABt+EViVPUAlKzgNDWgwLTxkYC0SRQAyNAwcfGJvChp6ZAtwwLtkOPQsWWTzXwA6RnCAXmQXdwhOHmpXCDBtfWQqymQdOChWAHJugC8+5C5OXT0ypnZkAHpZpSh8KABCBiZkSTwILRA8FpVIlrEqbt7kDTAoUABzHikZJMz9E3lTAGZfcf0pvBn57QAazgAE9eACAO4QYBQSQgHZhcRQCCBDTAG4gAC2EHA1Am7SoXR6rAAREMSSZyqxFGM5gtoMs1uUIloVFc4NQgA)